# How to return object from long running task while the task is in progress?

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library

I am creating a long running task and want to return an object from task if cancelled

```
private void HandleBackgroundTasks(object args)
{
  var handles = args as WaitHandle[];
  CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
  while (WaitHandle.WaitAny(handles) == 0 && !cancellationTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)
  {
     var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(BackgroundTask, cancellationTokenSource.Token);
     cancellationTokenSource.Token.Register(() => ResetCancellationTaskStatus());
  }
}

private void BackgroundTask()
{
  //long running task
  //task creates an object with task status and id
}

private void ResetCancellationTaskStatus()
{
  //Need to update the task status of object created in BackgroundTask method
}
```

Comment: _"want to return an object from task if cancelled"_ -- your title says "while the task is in progress". A cancelled task is not "in progress". So, which do you mean? Either way, _what have you tried_? What _specifically_ do you need help with?

Comment: @user344, why did you add the `aync-await` tag?  Your sample code does not use that at all.

Comment: Also, it matters a lot in what kind of app (asp.net or not) and how you interface with the 'foreground'.